# how to get a maximum values of two peaks of an array and take them away using for loops? any ideas?

Tags: java

how to get a maximum value of two peaks of an array and take them away using for loops? any ideas? 
was thinking to use 2 for loops to find the values in the array. i am using an acceloremeter and displaying the result within a graph but now i need to find the 2 peaks and take them away to determine the outcome and display it.

```
 SM.unregisterListener(this);
        File path = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
        File file = new File(path, "my_file-name.txt");
       // String filename = "my_file";
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file); //openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            for (double d : array) {
                String s = Double.toString(d) + ",";
                outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
            }

            String newline = "/n";
            outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());

            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

this code values are stored within a file so i can then display it within a graph

Comment: Your code has little to do with arrays. What are you trying to show by posting the code?

Comment: its an acceloremeter class and the values are stored in an array and then written to a file so i can convert the values from the file data to a graph in excel but now i need to find 2 peaks using for loops and take them away to get the answer and print it in a text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can find two peaks in one loop:

```
        File file = new File(path, "my_file-name.txt");
       // String filename = "my_file";
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file); //openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            double peak1, peak2;
            if(array.length >= 2) {
                peak1 = array[0];
                peak2 = array[1];
            } else { // not enough elements
                return; 
            }
            for (double d : array) {
                // peak2 is greater, leave it;
                // save new value to peak1 ?
                if(peak1 < peak2 && d > peak1) {
                    peak1 = d;
                } else if(d > peak2) { // peak1 is greater or d is less
                    peak2 = d;
                }
                String s = Double.toString(d) + ",";
                outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
            }

            String newline = "/n";
            outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());

            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Peaks: " + peak1 + " ; " + peak2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

See code sample [here](https://ideone.com/KFSFJs).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but see i already have data passed into an array through an acceloremeter its not just a random array, its throeing data at me and then i show the data results on a graph in excel but im trying to find the the two peaks and take them away from each other and print them as text if you have any ideas for that would really appreciate it. thanks

Comment: @JoeDobbs just use that I have posted in original answer. Code sample with random numbers is just for testing purposes.

Comment: you couldnt help me to find the peak as the first peak is thrown off by smaller peaks around it. i need to find the point around 40 as the first peak. the idea would be to separate the two peaks by a valley under 5. one way to do it is to find peak two, keep going backwards until it hits a valley...then keep going back untill peak one is found again. any chance you could help me with that ive posted the code below

Answer (score 0):

private void stopSensor() {

```
    SM.unregisterListener(this);
    File path = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File file = new File(path, "my_file-name.txt");
    // String filename = "my_file";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file); //openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        for (double d : array) {
            String s = Double.toString(d) + ",";
            outputStream.write(s.getBytes());
        }

        String newline = "/n";
        outputStream.write(newline.getBytes());

        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {

        double peak1, peak2;
        int peaklocation1, peaklocation2;


        if (array.length >= 2) {
            peak1 = array[0];
            peak2 = array[1];
            peaklocation1 = 0;
            peaklocation2 = 1;


        } else { // not enough elements
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            double d = array[i];
            // peak2 is greater, leave it;
            // save new value to peak1 ?
            if (peak1 < peak2 && d > peak1) {
                peak1 = d;
                peaklocation1 = i;
            } else if (d > peak2) { // peak1 is greater or d is less
                peak2 = d;
                peaklocation2 = i;

            }

        }
        int size = peaklocation1;
        size = peaklocation1 - peaklocation2 ;


        resultText.setText("Result:" + peaklocation1 );
        resultText2.setText("Result:" + peaklocation2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
       // System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```